# Correct .htaccess RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent hours looking for a solution, but .htaccess rules seem way over my head. I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wikka.php?wakka=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and I need it to be applied only if there is anything beyond the domain name, ie. `www.example.com/xyz` but NOT with just `www.example.com` because then I only need to display a simple `index.php` instead {no address translation}.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wikka.php?wakka=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

You just need to change the `*` (0 or more) in the `RewriteRule` pattern to `+` (1 or more). For example:

```
 RewriteRule (.+) wikka.php?wakka=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also removed the anchors `^` and `$`, since they are not necessary here. You are grabbing everything anyway, so saying you are grabbing everything from the start to the end is just not necessary.

Also, unless you require the query string from the original request I would remove the `QSA` flag. By itself this rule will result in a repeated query string of the form `?wakka=wikka.php&wakka=xyz` - where `xyz` is the intial request. This still "works" if reading the URL params with PHP as `wakka=xyz` will override the earlier parameter.

Comment: I suggest to _keep_ the `^` and `$` to make the expression more explicit, easier to grasp in its meaning...

Comment: Well, that's a matter of opinion. But if it helps with your own understanding and readability in this instance then keep the anchors.

Comment: In this case mod_rewrite will detect looping and stop it with `[IGNORING REWRITE]`, but I would avoid second processing with this `^(?!wikka\.php)(.+)$`

Comment: @Deadooshka That's certainly a valid point and in this case would result in a repeated query string (eg. `wikka.php?wakka=wikka.php&wakka=xyz` - which still "works") because of the `QSA` flag (which may or may not be necessary).

Comment: @Deadooshka However, I'm not convinced your suggestion would lead to increased efficiency (ie. avoid second processing). The second loop occurs anyway; regardless. `[IGNORING REWRITE]` isn't necessarily an error. Processing does at least stop at this point - which is the desired result. If you use a conditional (as you suggest) then the rule fails (good), but processing then continues through the rest of the file (which is unnecessary). It would be more efficient to have a _pre-exception_ like `RewriteRule ^wikka\.php$ - [L]` that prevents any further rules being processed.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm! Thank you!